# Adding more than one station to xml using obspy

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, obspy

I'm a new python user. I'm trying to use obspy to create xml for a seismic array. I downloaded the template found at https://docs.obspy.org/tutorial/code_snippets/stationxml_file_from_scratch.html.

```
import obspy
from obspy.core.inventory import Inventory, Network, Station, Channel, Site
from obspy.clients.nrl import NRL


# We'll first create all the various objects. These strongly follow the
# hierarchy of StationXML files.
inv = Inventory(
    # We'll add networks later.
    networks=[],
    # The source should be the id whoever create the file.
    source="ObsPy-Tutorial")

net = Network(
    # This is the network code according to the SEED standard.
    code="XX",
    # A list of stations. We'll add one later.
    stations=[],
    description="A test stations.",
    # Start-and end dates are optional.
    start_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 2))

sta = Station(
    # This is the station code according to the SEED standard.
    code="ABC",
    latitude=1.0,
    longitude=2.0,
    elevation=345.0,
    creation_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 2),
    site=Site(name="First station"),
    code="DEF",
    latitude=10.0,
    longitude=20.0,
    elevation=3450.0,
    creation_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 3),
    site=Site(name="Second station"))

cha = Channel(
    # This is the channel code according to the SEED standard.
    code="HHZ",
    # This is the location code according to the SEED standard.
    location_code="",
    # Note that these coordinates can differ from the station coordinates.
    latitude=1.0,
    longitude=2.0,
    elevation=345.0,
    depth=10.0,
    azimuth=0.0,
    dip=-90.0,
    sample_rate=200)

# By default this accesses the NRL online. Offline copies of the NRL can
# also be used instead
nrl = NRL()
# The contents of the NRL can be explored interactively in a Python prompt,
# see API documentation of NRL submodule:
# http://docs.obspy.org/packages/obspy.clients.nrl.html
# Here we assume that the end point of data logger and sensor are already
# known:
response = nrl.get_response( # doctest: +SKIP
    sensor_keys=['Streckeisen', 'STS-1', '360 seconds'],
    datalogger_keys=['REF TEK', 'RT 130 & 130-SMA', '1', '200'])


# Now tie it all together.
cha.response = response
sta.channels.append(cha)
net.stations.append(sta)
inv.networks.append(net)

# And finally write it to a StationXML file. We also force a validation against
# the StationXML schema to ensure it produces a valid StationXML file.
#
# Note that it is also possible to serialize to any of the other inventory
# output formats ObsPy supports.
inv.write("station.xml", format="stationxml", validate=True)
```

I'm stuck on a silly question: how can I add another station in `sta`? Something like

```
code="DEF",
latitude=10.0,
longitude=20.0,
elevation=3450.0,
creation_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 3),
site=Site(name="Second station"))
```

I'm using Spyder 5.3.3.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make another `Station` object, for example `sta2 = Station(code=...)`, and then add it to the inventory using `net.stations.append(sta2)` :

```
import obspy
from obspy.core.inventory import Inventory, Network, Station, Channel, Site
from obspy.clients.nrl import NRL


# We'll first create all the various objects. These strongly follow the
# hierarchy of StationXML files.
inv = Inventory(
    # We'll add networks later.
    networks=[],
    # The source should be the id whoever create the file.
    source="ObsPy-Tutorial")

net = Network(
    # This is the network code according to the SEED standard.
    code="XX",
    # A list of stations. We'll add one later.
    stations=[],
    description="A test stations.",
    # Start-and end dates are optional.
    start_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 2))

sta = Station(
    # This is the station code according to the SEED standard.
    code="ABC",
    latitude=1.0,
    longitude=2.0,
    elevation=345.0,
    creation_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 2),
    site=Site(name="First station"))

# Second station
sta2 = Station(
    code="DEF",
    latitude=10.0,
    longitude=20.0,
    elevation=3450.0,
    creation_date=obspy.UTCDateTime(2016, 1, 3),
    site=Site(name="Second station"))

cha = Channel(
    # This is the channel code according to the SEED standard.
    code="HHZ",
    # This is the location code according to the SEED standard.
    location_code="",
    # Note that these coordinates can differ from the station coordinates.
    latitude=1.0,
    longitude=2.0,
    elevation=345.0,
    depth=10.0,
    azimuth=0.0,
    dip=-90.0,
    sample_rate=200)

# By default this accesses the NRL online. Offline copies of the NRL can
# also be used instead
nrl = NRL()
# The contents of the NRL can be explored interactively in a Python prompt,
# see API documentation of NRL submodule:
# http://docs.obspy.org/packages/obspy.clients.nrl.html
# Here we assume that the end point of data logger and sensor are already
# known:
response = nrl.get_response( # doctest: +SKIP
    sensor_keys=['Streckeisen', 'STS-1', '360 seconds'],
    datalogger_keys=['REF TEK', 'RT 130 & 130-SMA', '1', '200'])


# Now tie it all together.
cha.response = response
sta.channels.append(cha)
net.stations.append(sta)
# add second station to network
net.stations.append(sta2)
inv.networks.append(net)

# And finally write it to a StationXML file. We also force a validation against
# the StationXML schema to ensure it produces a valid StationXML file.
# Note that it is also possible to serialize to any of the other inventory
# output formats ObsPy supports.
inv.write("station.xml", format="stationxml", validate=True)
```

You can double check that the new station is there with `print(inv)` (I find XML files rather hard to read sometimes):

```
Inventory created at 2022-10-14T00:33:59.433461Z
    Created by: ObsPy 1.3.0
            https://www.obspy.org
    Sending institution: ObsPy-Tutorial
    Contains:
        Networks (1):
            XX
        Stations (2):
            XX.ABC (First station)
            XX.DEF (Second station)
        Channels (1):
            XX.ABC..HHZ
```

You can use a similar method to add channels to a station using `sta.channels.append(new channel)`. Cheers!